# How do I set a variable within an Angular JS service to the response data from an $http call within an AngularJS service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following service which I eventually want to cache. However, I can't seem to figure out how set a variable within the service to the response data from the REST call using $http in Angular.

```
routerApp.service('activityService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

    this.temp = null;

    this.setTemp(x) {
        this.temp = x;
    }

    this.getActivities = function(x) {

        var promise = $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'my url is here...'
        }).then(function(response) {
            //setTemp(response.data); //definitely wont work
            return response.data;
        });

        //how to set temp to response.data???
       setTemp(promise.data); //doesn't work - 
    };
});
```

I don't know JS (or angular for that matter) very well. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to cache the angular service, it's guaranteed to be a singleton.
If you mean to cache the response data, you will create a cache object in your service.

Now about the main question. In this code there is misuse of promises not angular services. Promises are asynchronous, meaning that a callback provided to `.then()` will be executed some time later, when request is finished. Besides `.then` returns another promise, which you should return from `activityService.getActivities` method.

```
this.getActivities = function(x) {
    var promise = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'my url is here...'
    }).then(function(response) {
        setTemp(response.data); //meaning that setTemp somehow modifies it's argument
        return response.data;
    });
    return promise;
};
```

Then in one of your controllers you will use this service's method attaching `.then` to it's return value.

```
.controller('someController', function (activityService) {
        activityService.getActivities()
            .then(function (data) {
                    doSomethingWithResponse(data);
                }
        });
```

Comment: Yeah, I meant cache the response data. And thank you! I definitely learned something from this.